# Implementing stacks and Queue

Tags: c++, stack, queue

What is the best solution to implement Stacks and Queues:

- From scratch (list like)
- Using composition (using a list)
- Using inheritance (deriving from list)

Criteria to use: time complexity, code simplicity, maintainability.

Comment: which language ?

Comment: the language I am using  is c++

Answer (score 0):

Stacks and Queues are relatively simple data structures. If properly used they will usually have a time complexity of O(1) for all implementations. You just need to get data from the front of the queue or stack and insert the new data at either the back or the front respectively. Therefore, you don't need to search the data structure because you know where to insert and delete data. https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/

As for code simplicity and maintenance, creating your code from scratch will most likely be the worst. You will have to do all the work yourself and will have to fix anything that breaks all by yourself. (To be honest, I like to try to make data structures myself because I get to learn a lot about the intricate details despite the clear disadvantages.)

Inheritance shouldn't be necessary unless you need to add extra functionality to the list for your particular use case. If you don't need to change anything then at best you are basically just using the standard list and in worst case you are probably just doing extra work.

Just using the regular list has the advantage of already being made for you and it is maintained by other programmers. Therefore it is probably best.

However, C++ has a queue and stack template that will probably be best for most use cases so if you don't need anything special I would just use that.

Hope this is helpful for you.